# Smoothness of function from differentiable manifold

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology

Suppose we have a set $M$,
a $C^k$-atlas $\{\varphi_\alpha:U_\alpha\to\mathbb{R}^n\}_{\alpha\in A}$ on $M$,
and a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$.

Is there any relation or restriction between
the differentiability class of a transition map $\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}$ (class $C^k$)
and that of $f\circ\varphi_\gamma^{-1}$ (class $C^l$) for any $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ in $A$?

For instance, is $\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}$ in the differentiability class of $f\circ\varphi_\gamma^{-1}$ ($k \ge l$)?
Since $f\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}=f\circ(\varphi_\alpha^{-1}\circ\varphi_\alpha)\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}=(f\circ\varphi_\alpha^{-1})\circ(\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1})$,
where $f\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}$ and $f\circ\varphi_\alpha^{-1}$ are in class $C^l$ while $\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}$ is in class $C^k$.

Comment: What is $\varphi$?

Comment: Charts, elements of the atlas, are bijections between $U$, subsets of $M$ whose union is the whole of $M$, and open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. ([Differential structure - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure#Definition))

Comment: Element of which atlas? Also, it should be $\varphi^{-1}$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Well, a differentiable manifold always comes with an atlas, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should be $\varphi^{-1}$, my apologies.

Comment: As for which chart (I suppose you mean that), $\varphi_\alpha$ or $\varphi_\beta$.
Since $f$ is defined from $M$ so any $\varphi$ whose domain and range are valid would do.

To be more specific, let all $\varphi_\alpha$ where $\alpha\in A$ in the class $C^l$.

Comment: This post is so unclear: (1) $M$ can't be just a set: an atlas is defined only on a topological manifold. (2) What kind of atlas are you referring to? A smooth atlas? A $C^k$-atlas? or just topological one. (3) 
 you can't ask what is the smoothness of $\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}$: this is the definition of a $C^k$/smooth/analytic atlas. (4) if $\varphi$ is from the same atlas $\{\varphi_\alpha\}$, then $\varphi = \varphi_\gamma$? (5) your $f$ is arbitrary and has nothing to do with the atlas, how would you except any relation?

Comment: Also, (6) what is the metric you mentioned in the title?

Comment: First, $M$ can be just a set, at least that's what Wikipedia said.
Second, $C^{k}$-atlas.
Third, as the second answer stated, $k$ can be thought of as fixed.
Fourth, I'm not sure what it means but I guess my last comment answered it.
Fifth, at the transition, $f\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}=f\circ\varphi_\alpha^{-1}\circ\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1}$ so I suppose if there will be any relation here.
Sixth, another apology, at first I suppose $f$ be a metric but I suppose that to generalize the problem will leads to rather interesting result.